# How to properly do multi language in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to refactor our ElasticSearch backend and right now, we are using a different index, per language. Which means we have to do a lot of excess insertions (since we have 8 that we need to support).

The problem is that languages will be added / removed dynamically sometimes. Furthermore, a lot of **static** data is attached to the items as well, think about prices, feature ids, availability, statuses, etc. These are all used in combination with aggregations for faceted search.

To have all this data duplicated for each language, in a separate index, seems rather cumbersome. Therefore I am wondering if there is a better solution (perhaps using properties), to index the name of the item, in the same index, for different languages with the according analyzer for each property.

If so, I would like to be able to **delete** a defined language, and **insert** a defined language as well. Which I now do by by creating / dropping indices accordingly.

I have tried a number of approaches (multiple indexes, language detection, etc) but I have not yet found something that felt like 'the right way'. In short, the current approach works for now, but it just feels awkward.

The actual mapping is as follows, and an index `documents-%lang%` is used:

```json
'name': {
    'type' : 'text',
    'analyzer': 'simple'
},
'code': {
    'type': 'keyword'
},
'popularity': {
    'type': 'long'
},
'search_words': {
    'type': 'keyword'
},
'features': {
    'type': 'nested',
    'properties': {
        'id': {
            'type': 'keyword'
        },
        'values': {
            'type': 'keyword'
        }
    }
},
'storefronts': {
    'type': 'integer'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch provides a *single* article about this, which I chose for a very good reason. It allows you to have multiple languages by fields, and then aggregate those fields with e.g. a base language. Which is great when content is dynamically getting indexed.

[Read the article here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/one-lang-fields.html)